# How to serve custom ads for clients on my site?

Tags: advertising, service

Are there any ad serving systems, that allow webmasters to serve ads from their clients on their sites? The client provides an image/text and a link and the website displays the ad in designated spaces. The website would display only ads from their own customers (nothing from a public ad network like adsense).

Can you please provide examples of such ad serving solutions? Preferrably free/opensource.

Answer (score 1):

[Openx](http://www.openx.org/)

Comment: free, and awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ad server like [AdSpeed.com](http://adspeed.com) to manage, serve and track ads provided by your advertisers/clients.